# How is it possible to current user info on page in WordPress?

Tags: login, user-meta, avatar

I am new at WordPress. I have need to display current user info on page: avatar, name, lastname, login...
I have spent several hour on web, but could not find clean solution:
How is it possible to do this in WordPress?

Thank You

Comment: You might want to remove the request for a plugin recommendation, if you don't want your post to be closed, as they are off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has [wp_get_current_user()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_current_user/) function for getting the current (logged in) user, which you could use. If the returned [WP_User](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user/) object doesn't have all the details you need, you can get either all or a specific user meta with [get_user_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_meta/). For getting the user's avatar, you could use [get_avatar()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_avatar/).

Have a look at the function docs for more details and their *User Contributed Notes* for some usage examples.